# EOFException / SocketException when working with sockets and threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, socketexception, eofexception

This socket application works perfectly fine until I add support for multiple client connections to the server. Then I get a EOFException from the client, and a SocketException: Socket closed from the server.

Server.java:

```
public class Server {

    static final int PORT = 8005;
    static final int QUEUE = 50;

    public Server() {
        while (true) {
            try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT, QUEUE);
                 Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                 DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                 DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            output.writeUTF("Hey, this is the server!");
                            output.flush();
                            System.out.println(input.readUTF());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server();
    }

}
```

Client.java:

```
public class Client {

    static final String HOST = "localhost";
    static final int PORT = 8005;

    public Client() {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
             DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
             DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
        ) {
            System.out.println(input.readUTF());
            output.writeUTF("Hey, this is the client!");
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple problems here:

1. You're creating a new `ServerSocket` for each pass through the loop.  For a multi-client server you should instead be opening one `ServerSocket` and calling `accept()` on it for each client that connects.
2. Try-with-resources closes all resources it's provided with as soon as the `try` block is exited.  You're creating a `Thread` that uses `output` but executes independently of the `try` block, so the execution flow is leaving the `try` block before `thread` finishes executing, resulting in `socket` (and `output`) being closed before the thread is able to use them.  This is one of those situations where your resources need to be used outside the scope of the `try` block (in the thread you create to use them), so try-with-resources can't do all your resource handling for you.

I would rearrange your server code to something like:

```
public class Server {

    static final int PORT = 8005;
    static final int QUEUE = 50;

    public Server() {
        // create serverSocket once for all connections
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT, QUEUE)) {
            while (true) {
                // accept a client connection, not in a try-with-resources so this will have to be explicitly closed
                final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // limit scope of input/output to where they're actually used
                        try (DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
                            output.writeUTF("Hey, this is the server!");
                            output.flush();
                            System.out.println(input.readUTF());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // implicitly close socket when done with it
                        try {
                            socket.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            System.out.println();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                thread.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server();
    }
}
```

Code is commented somewhat to explain some of the moves.  Also note that the `socket.close()` call is in its own try-catch block to ensure that it's called even if the I/O streams throw an exception.  It could equivalently (or perhaps more correctly now that I think about it) been placed in a `finally` block on the I/O stream try-catch block.